# cross-sell products are not getting added while doing add to cart

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, addtocart, cross-sells

In the product page **cross-sell products** are showing with checkboxes.
When I check some checkboxes and then click "add to cart" then the product along with the checked cross-sell products should added to the cart.
But only the product is getting added to the cart except the checked crosssell product. 
I found that the code for adding product is written in
`app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/cotrollers/CartController.php -->addAction()`
Inside it some code is as follows..

```
$cart   = $this->_getCart();
$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
echo "<pre>";print_r($params);echo "</pre>";exit;
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();
```

when I tried to print the $params then following parameters came..

```
Array
(
[uenc] => aHR0cDovL2Frc2hheWEuYWZpehyuSDepYS5jb20vcG9zdGJveGVzL3N0yu76ygEtbWljcm8tcG93ZXJsb2NrLTNtLTEwZnQtMC0zMy01MjM,
[product] => 19
[checkboxes] => Array
    (
        [0] => 534
        [1] => 222
    )

[qty] => 1
[related_product] => 
)
```

Is it a wrong format of $params ?
If no, then why only 19 is getting saved and 534 and 222 is not getting added ?

i.e. it is **getting the crosssell product ids** but **not adding** it.
Could anyone suggest what should be the right way to add $params ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In default Magento, cross-sell products are not supposed to be added to cart from product page along with the main product. That said, you can change your template file to mimic as cross-sell products like related products. For that you can try with just changing the name attribute in checkboxes. Change it from 'checkboxes' to 'related_product' and see if it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your related products checkbox name to `related_product`, Magento used this parameter in `Mage_Checkout_CartController` `addAction()` method. See below code:

```
public function addAction()
    {
        if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
            $this->_goBack();
            return;
        }
        $cart   = $this->_getCart();
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        try {
            if (isset($params['qty'])) {
                $filter = new Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                    array('locale' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode())
                );
                $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
            }

            $product = $this->_initProduct();
            $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');    // Related product items
.....
.....
.....
}
```

And in your case related products checkbox name is `checkbox` instead `related_product`. It should work once you change checkbox name.